# How to resend letter if email not confirmed, FLASK?

Tags: flask

Am trying to resend email to any one that not yet confirmed his account .

**models.py**

```
class Subscribers(Base):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50))
    confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default=False)

    def confirm(self, token):
        s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        try:
            data = s.loads(token)
        except:
            return False
        if data.get('confirm') != self.id:
            return False
        self.confirmed = True
        db.session.add(self)
        return True

    def generate_confirmation_token(self, expiration=3600):
        s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'], expiration)
        return s.dumps({'confirm': self.id})

    def get_token(self, expiration=1800):
        s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'], expiration)
        return s.dumps({'email': self.id}).decode('utf-8')

    @staticmethod
    def verify_token(token):
        s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        try:
            data = s.loads(token)
        except:
            return None
        id = data.get('email')
        if id:
            return User.query.get(id)
        return None
```

This is the function where the confirmation process handled:

```
@app.route('/send-confirmation/<email>/<token>')
def confirm(token,email):
    subre = Subscribers.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
    if subre.confirmed:
        flash('Э.почта уже подтверждена.')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    if subre.confirm(token):
        subre.confirmed = True
        db.session.add(subre)
        db.session.commit()
        send_email(subre.email, 'Благодарим Вас за подписку на наш сайт', 'auth/subscribe/thanks', subre=subre, token=token)
        flash('Вы подтвердили свою электронную почту, спасибо!')
    else:
        flash('Ссылка для подтверждения является недействительным или истек.')
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Tell now everything is working very well, am trying to fetch each account that not yet confirmed by sending them another message asking them to confirm there account, here is the function :

```
@app.before_request
def resend_confirmation():
    subscribers = Subscribers.query.filter_by(confirmed=False)
    for sub in subscribers:
        email = sub.email
        token = email.generate_confirmation_token()
        send_email(email, 'Подтверждение по электронной почте было отправлено Вам по электронной почте.',
                'auth/email/resend', email=email, token=token)
```

Here am getting an error says:

`AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'generate_confirmation_token'`

i tried to add `__unicode__` function in the model but without avail .

Please any help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call generate_confirmation_token method on email, but you should use Subscribers instance:

```
@app.before_request
def resend_confirmation():
    subscribers = Subscribers.query.filter_by(confirmed=False)
    for sub in subscribers:
        token = sub.generate_confirmation_token()
        send_email(sub.email, 'Подтверждение по электронной почте было отправлено Вам по электронной почте.',
            'auth/email/resend', email=email, token=token)
```